# How to insert into clojure vector based on ordering key

Tags: arrays, vector, clojure

I have the following clojure vector where each element is an ArrayMap:

```clj
[{:title "Step 2", :order 1}
 {:title "Step 1", :order 0}
 {:title "Step 3", :order 2}]
```

and I want to organize it into a new vector which contains each title indexed based on its corresponding order number as follows:

```clj
["Step 1" "Step 2" "Step 3"]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> (map :title (sort-by :order v))
("Step 1" "Step 2" "Step 3")
```

If you really need the result to be a vector:

```
> (mapv :title (sort-by :order v))
["Step 1" "Step 2" "Step 3"]
```